# Measures of "correlation" between two orderings

Tags: co.combinatorics, st.statistics, order-theory

An easy question perhaps?

Taking a (fictional) concrete example, let's say I have two ranking methods for HTML documents: PageRank and HITS. I derive an ordered list over the same set of documents according to their rank values (there can be ties) for both ranking methods.

Now, I want to quantify how much the two orderings correlate. I'm not interested in the absolute values of the ranking measures, but I'm looking for measures of correlation between the orderings.

I can think of some intuitive correlation measures one could apply like "average distance" or such:

${\displaystyle\frac{\sum_{doc_i\in Docs}\mathrm{abs}(pos_{rank1}(doc_i) - pos_{rank2}(doc_i))}{|Docs|^2}}$

but I'm wondering if anyone knows of any standard techniques I could check out?

In particular, I would prefer a symmetric measure which is easy to intuit and whose results are tangible/"portable". I've a number of different orderings which I'll be comparing pair-wise, but the set of $Docs$ remains the same.

Many thanks in advance!

(having difficulty tagging... please feel free to edit tags)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard approach to computing the correlation between two total orders is [Kendall's $\tau$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_rank_correlation_coefficient), defined as the difference between the number of agreeing pairs and disagreeing pairs (in rank) divided by $\binom{n}{2}$.

If you only have partial orders, then [things get a little trickier](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15955/defining-average-rank-when-not-every-ranking-covers-the-whole-set/15958#15958).

Comment: Many thanks for the answer and pointers! "Rank correlation" and Google was what I needed... :)